# How to select column content based on max value within groups of another column. Select marker name based of maximun value for each gene

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, max, aggregate

I have the following df:

```
Gene pval  Marker
A      0.12     M1
A      0.11     M2
B      0.33     M3
B      0.55     M4
B      0.06     M5
D      0.03     M7
D      0.04     M8
```

I want to get the marker name based on the maximum pvalue for each gene.
What I have tried:

```
peak_marker <-df[which.max(df[,2]),3]
```

But the result is the marker name with the highest pvalue in the entire data frame not the marker name with the highest pval for each gene.

I also tried this with no success:

```
aggregate(df$pval, by = list(df$Gene), which.max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  filter(val == max(val))
```

Returns:

```
  # A tibble: 3 x 3
  # Groups:   Gene [3]
    Gene    val Marker
    <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
  1 A      0.12 M1    
  2 B      0.55 M4    
  3 D      0.04 M8
```

Or, if we want to get rid of the grouping:

```
  df %>% 
    group_by(Gene) %>% 
    filter(val == max(val)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions using both `base` and `data.table`!

Reading in the data:

```r
library(data.table)
df = fread("Gene pval  Marker
A      0.12     M1
A      0.11     M2
B      0.33     M3
B      0.55     M4
B      0.06     M5
D      0.03     M7
D      0.04     M8")
setDF(df)
```

With `base` we're essentially going to go through each unique value for `Gene` and manually subset the data

```
sapply(unique(df[,'Gene']), FUN = function(g) {
    d = df[df$Gene == g,]
    d[which.max(d[,2]),3]
})
#>    A    B    D 
#> "M1" "M4" "M8"
```

With `data.table` we can use the `by` argument to break the data into groups and then access the part of the data within the group using `.SD` (which is a Subset of the Data)

```
setDT(df)
df[,.SD[order(-pval)][1,Marker], by = Gene]
#>    Gene V1
#> 1:    A M1
#> 2:    B M4
#> 3:    D M8
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are very close to make it with `aggregate`, but you perhaps need some additional help from `merge`.

Here is a base R solution, where `aggregate` + `merge` were used, i.e.,

```
dfout <- merge(aggregate(pval~Gene,df,max),df,all.x = T)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Gene pval Marker
1    A 0.12     M1
2    B 0.55     M4
3    D 0.04     M8
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D"), pval = c(0.12, 
0.11, 0.33, 0.55, 0.06, 0.03, 0.04), Marker = c("M1", "M2", "M3", 
"M4", "M5", "M7", "M8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```